# How do I tell pattern searcher the order in which to search for patterns given in general form?

Tags: pattern-matching, functional-style, code-request

I have a *really long* sequence of `Symbols` inside a function, say `nonCommute[a,b,c,e,e,f,g,b,i,j]`, and I am implementing a recursive algorithm using `RepeatedReplace` with the rule:

```
rule = nonCommute[left___,x_,middle___,x_,right___] :> f[Length[middle]]
```

The right hand side actually isn't `f`, but is really a *sum* of more `nonCommute` with slightly smaller `Sequences` than the original whose complexity depends on `Length[middle]`.   Consequently, the algorithm goes *much* *much* faster if patterns with the shortest `midddle___` are matched first, followed `middle___` of increasing lengths.

Is it possible to tell the pattern searcher to look for patterns with the shorter `middle___` first?

**What I have so far**

I just do the ugly thing of writing out the first few patterns explicitly in the order I want, and hope `middle___` doesn't get too long:

```
uglyRules = {nonCommute[left___,x_,x_,right___] :> f0[(*...*)],
        nonCommute[left___,x_,a1_,x_,right___] :> f1[(*...*)],
        nonCommute[left___,x_,a1_,a2_,x_,right___] :> f2[(*...*)],
        nonCommute[left___,x_,a1_,a2_,a3_,x_,right___] :> f3[(*...*)],
        nonCommute[left___,x_,a1_,a2_,a3_,a4_,x_,right___] :> f4[(*...*)] }
```

**Bonus**

It turns out that `nonCommute` has cyclic property:  `nonCommute[a,b___] = nonCommute[b___,a]`.  This means, we can make the algorithm go even faster if we also check for patterns that goes the other way (*i.e.* wraps around).  I have implemented this for the first two of my `uglyRules` above.

```
uglyRules = {nonCommute[left___,x_,x_,right___] :> f0[(*...*)],
             nonCommute[x_,center___,x_] :> f0[(*...*)],

             nonCommute[left___,x_,a1_,x_,right___] :> f1[(*...*)],
             nonCommute[a1_,x_,center___,x_] :> f1[(*...*)],
             nonCommute[x_,center___,x_,a1] :> f1[(*...*)] }
```

Can this fact be included in the pattern searcher, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is certainly possible to tell the pattern matcher to search for the shortest pattern.

```
rule = nonCommute[left___, x_, Shortest[middle__], x_, right___] :> {middle};
nonCommute[a, b, q, b, a] /. rule
```

results in {q} and

```
nonCommute[a, b, q, q, b, a] /. rule
```

results in {q,q}

but you should be somewhat cautious because that does not result in {} and this

```
nonCommute[a, b, q, q, q, b, a] /. rule
```

results in just {q}

I need more specific information to understand what your bonus question is. Perhaps you can replace the (* ... *) with something, possibly even something you aren't going to do, but which will be sufficient for others to understand what you want to extract or replace.

EDIT: Revised to replace middle___ (triple underscore) with middle__ (double underscore)

Comment: This is *exactly* what I need.  For some reason, Bill, when I run your examples on my machine (Mathematica 9.0.1), I get the expected result {} for all of them.

Comment: The bonus is pretty easy to understand; I guess I didn't do a good job explaining it in my question.  Basically, the elements of `nonCommute` can be thought to be arranged in a ring (instead of in a line).  Then, the *distance* between repeated elements `x_` is shorter of the two sequences around the ring.  *e.g.* in `nonCommute[a,b,c,a,d]` the rule should trigger on `{d}` and not `{b,c,a}`.  Get it?

Comment: Using Shortest with a triple underscore pattern is going to give an empty list if you have any adjacent pair of identical items. I had first used double underscore and it looks like some of that incorrectly leaked into my answer. My apologies. Try double and see if that works correctly in all your cases. Next, your cyclic explanation makes much more sense. I don't see a quick simple solution. What if you joined two copies of all your arguments together and looked for patterns in that? Could you correctly extract what you need from that longer list? I'll see if I can think of anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly set a list of replacement rules as `Downvalues` of your `Symbol` in the order you prefer:

```
DownValues[nonCommute] = 
  {HoldPattern@nonCommute[left___, x_, x_, right___] :>
     f0[(*...*)], 
   HoldPattern@nonCommute[left___, x_, a1_, x_, right___] :> 
    f1[(*...*)], 
   HoldPattern@nonCommute[left___, x_, a1_, a2_, x_, right___] :> 
    f2[(*...*)], 
   HoldPattern@nonCommute[left___, x_, a1_, a2_, a3_, x_, right___] :>
     f3[(*...*)], 
   HoldPattern@
     nonCommute[left___, x_, a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, x_, right___] :> 
    f4[(*...*)]};
```

This order will further be used by the pattern matcher when looking for a pattern which matches an expression with `Head` `nonCommute` as reflected in the `Definition` for `nonCommute`:

```
Definition[nonCommute]
```

> ```
> nonCommute[left___,x_,x_,right___]:=f0[]
>
> nonCommute[left___,x_,a1_,x_,right___]:=f1[]
>
> nonCommute[left___,x_,a1_,a2_,x_,right___]:=f2[]
>
> nonCommute[left___,x_,a1_,a2_,a3_,x_,right___]:=f3[]
>
> nonCommute[left___,x_,a1_,a2_,a3_,a4_,x_,right___]:=f4[]
> ```

Quick check:

```
nonCommute[a, b, b, b, b, b, b, e]
```

> ```
> f0[]
> ```

as expected.